# If key exists i json file

Tags: json, key, exists

Loading a normal json file. How do I find if this key exists in json string
-> jsonstreng["kjoretoydataListe"][0]["kjennemerke"][1]["kjennemerke"]

Doing this of course without breaking my program if it's not.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using python

Comment: Please post the snippet of JSON object with the key here. Also share the error you are getting.

Comment: if jsonstreng["kjoretoydataListe"][0]["kjennemerke"][1]["kjennemerke"]: gets error IndexError if not present.

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonstreng = {
    "kjoretoydataListe":
    [
        {
            "kjoretoyId": {"kjennemerke":"EK 17058","understellsnummer":"5YJXCCE29GF009633"},
            "forstegangsregistrering": {"registrertForstegangNorgeDato":"2016-09-07"},
            "kjennemerke": [
                {"fomTidspunkt":"2016-09-07T00:00:00+02:00","kjennemerke":"EK 17058","kjennemerkekategori":"KJORETOY",
                "kjennemerketype":{"kodeBeskrivelse":"Sorte tegn p- hvit bunn","kodeNavn":"Ordin-re kjennemerker","kodeVerdi":"ORDINART","tidligereKodeVerdi":[]}},{"fomTidspunkt":"2022-08-19T17:04:04.334+02:00","kjennemerke":"GTD","kjennemerkekategori":"PERSONLIG"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}

def checkIfKeyExistsInDict(in_dict, i_key):
    if(isinstance(in_dict, dict)):
        if(i_key in in_dict):
            print(i_key + " found in: " + str(in_dict))
            print()
        
        for j_key in in_dict:
            checkIfKeyExistsInDict(in_dict[j_key], i_key)
    elif(isinstance(in_dict, list)):
        for j_key in range(len(in_dict)):
            checkIfKeyExistsInDict(in_dict[j_key], i_key)

        
checkIfKeyExistsInDict(jsonstreng, "kjennemerke")
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Python, the way to find if key (let's say "kjennemerke") is present in a JSON object (let's say "jsonstreng") is:

```
if ("kjennemerke" in jsonstreng):
  """If body goes here"""
  pass
```

Just for info, if you are trying to do the same in thing in JavaScript the if condition above will look like as shown below:

```
let jsonstreng_with_key = {
    "kjennemerke": 1
} 

let jsonstreng_without_key = {} // Empty object 

if(jsonstreng_with_key.hasOwnProperty('kjennemerke')){
    console.log("jsonstreng_with_key has key 'kjennemerke'");
} else {
    console.log("jsonstreng_with_key does not have key 'kjennemerke'");
}

if(jsonstreng_without_key.hasOwnProperty("kjennemerke")){
    console.log("jsonstreng_without_key has key 'kjennemerke'");
} else {
    console.log("jsonstreng_without_key does not have key 'kjennemerke'");
}
```

Comment: The problem is "kjennemerke" is used in many keys. I need to find the whole key.

Comment: Could you paste a snippet of the JSON object here?

Comment: {"kjoretoydataListe":[{"kjoretoyId":{"kjennemerke":"EK 17058","understellsnummer":"5YJXCCE29GF009633"},"forstegangsregistrering":{"registrertForstegangNorgeDato":"2016-09-07"},"kjennemerke":[{"fomTidspunkt":"2016-09-07T00:00:00+02:00","kjennemerke":"EK 17058","kjennemerkekategori":"KJORETOY","kjennemerketype":{"kodeBeskrivelse":"Sorte tegn p� hvit bunn","kodeNavn":"Ordin�re kjennemerker","kodeVerdi":"ORDINART","tidligereKodeVerdi":[]}},{"fomTidspunkt":"2022-08-19T17:04:04.334+02:00","kjennemerke":"GTD","kjennemerkekategori":"PERSONLIG","kjennemerketype":

Comment: Am loading the object you have given into a Python dict. Then I shall process it to find the key.